# How to remove languages

Tags: content-management

There are few languages in CMS other than English, which are no longer needed.

I have removed them from `control panel > delete language`, but after a log out & login, they re appear.

What am i doing wrong here.

using Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Are the languages still present at the path `/sitecore/system/Languages`. Try to delete them at that path

Comment: When I remove them from control  panel, they are gone and also not seen under /system/. But after logging in again, they come back

Comment: Can you delete it from the `/sitecore/system/Languages` directly and see if they come back again

Comment: That was how I tried first. When that did not work, tried removing from control panel

Comment: Do you have any errors in the log. Once the delete is done, before log out, see if the languages are in the recycle bin. Moreover, make sure you are checking the correct database. It might be that the items are being deleted but being published again

Comment: Do you have any Serialization tools in your project like Unicorn or TDS which will restore the languages?